# Get keys of the down node in vert.x Hazelcast cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, vert.x

I am making one vert.x hazelcast like this:

```
 ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();

    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);

    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
      if (res.succeeded()) {
        Vertx vertx = res.result();
         vertx.deployVericle(Verticle.getClassName());
       mgr.getHazelcastInstance.getCluster().addMembershipListener( new ClusterMembershipListener() );
      } else {
        // failed!
      }
    });
```

Now lets say I deploy n nodes in my cluster. I also write a listener to get notification when a node goes down like this:

```
public class ClusterMembershipListener
     implements MembershipListener {

public void memberAdded(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
  System.err.println("Added: " + membershipEvent);
}

public void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
       System.err.println("Removed: " + membershipEvent);
     }

public void memberAttributeChanged(MemberAttributeEvent memberAttributeEvent) {
       System.err.println("Member attribute changed: " + memberAttributeEvent);
     }

}
```

Now, Whenever a node is down I want to get names of all keys this node holds, and want to call other nodes in the cluster that hold the backup keys.

I want to run a scheduler service. So I was thinking, when a node goes down, I recover all the keys in that node and then call those nodes which have backup of those keys.

```
//get owner of that key in other node when the original node is down
PartitionService partitionService = Hazelcast.getPartitionService();
Partition partition = partitionService.getPartition(key);
Member ownerMember = partition.getOwner();

//reschedule the task 
     IExecutorService executorService = 
          hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService( "default" );

       Callable<Schedule> task = new Schedule();
      Future<String> future = executorService.submitToMember( task, ownerMember );
      String echoResult = future.get();
```

I checked here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Member.html
and I dont find any APIs which will give me all keys.

Is there a way I am missing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but when a node is down, its down. There is no data in a jvm that does not exist i.e. HC node that is down. You can use hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService().getPartition(<<key>>) to maintain housekeeping at your end. Btw, would you mind sharing how exactly do you intend to call other nodes in the cluster and what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @wildnez: I want to run a scheduler service. So I was thinking, when a node goes down, I recover all the keys in that node and then call those nodes which have backup of those keys. I have updated what I want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to keep track of keys, primary or backup, as Hazelcast recovers the data of the lost node from backups stored on other nodes in the cluster. This happens automatically as soon as a failure is detected in the cluster.

You have ways to determine if backup was restored and cluster is in normal operating mode, see the API: `hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService().isClusterSafe()`

Once the cluster has recovered, you can then submit scheduler jobs specific to keys. See this:

```
hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("my-executor-service").executeOnKeyOwner(new Runnable(), My_Key);
```

Comment: The problem is the keys might determine the rescheduling of some jobs. I agree re calibration will be done, but lets say I had stored some cron jobs for sending emails. Now since the cron stored in original was lost, I dont want to reschedule for all users in the recovered node. i want to do only for those whose schedules were lost.

Comment: Then you need DurableExecutorService: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#durable-executor-service

Comment: Are you flagging users which have email sent? I'd use EntryProcessors (or `DurableExecutorService` too) on user map & flag the users which has email's sent. OTOH, there's `PartitionLostListener` which will let you know when a partition is lost with it's backup. That's when you need to re-send emails

Comment: @sertug: I  encountered PartitionLostListener . However, I think I need to map keys on respective partitions on own. I was hoping Hazelcast will give such facility. Right Now I am thinking to collect all lost partitions in PartitionLostListener and again recalibrate the keys once they are migrated.

Comment: @sertug: By the way any example on how to use DurableExecutorService ?

Comment: See examples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-executor/durable-executor-service), however, I don't get the part why you need to "recalibrate the keys", since hazelcast does distribute the keys itself by an hashing algorithm and partitions are equally distributed to members. You just send a task on a key and hazelcast will execute it where key is located. You don't need to worry about key locations in short.